# What is E[X|X+Y < z] with X, Y independent Normals?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, convolution, truncated-normal-distribution

Let $X\sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$ and $Cov(X,Y)=\sigma_{XY}$. Define $Z=X+Y$.

I know that $E[X|Z=z]=\mu_X + \frac{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_X^2+2\sigma_{XY}+\sigma_Y^2}(z-\mu_X-\mu_Y)$.

But what is $E[X|Z\leq z]$?

Can I just integrate over all possible realizations of $Z\leq z$ and use linearity to do the following?

$$
\begin{align*}E[X|Z\leq z] & = \mu_X + \frac{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_X^2+2\sigma_{XY}+\sigma_Y^2}(E[Z|Z\leq z]-\mu_Z)\\
& = \mu_X + \frac{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_{XY}}{\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+2\sigma_{XY}+\sigma_Y^2}}\frac{\phi(\frac{z-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})}{\Phi(\frac{z-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z})}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation),
\begin{align}
E(X|Z\le z)
  &=E(E(X|Z)|Z\le z)
\\&=E(a + bZ|Z\le z)
\\&=a + bE(Z|Z\le z).
\end{align}